# Adding .mes and .mc files to a c++ project in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to compile a piece of code to a static library that was developed using visual studio version 6 in vs2010. During compilation I see errors related to error codes that were defined in .mes and .mc files as I didn't add these files to source files or header files, but they are part of include directories.
Can some one let me know how to add .mes and .mc files to a vs 2010 project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a content of .mes and .mc files?

Comment: .mes file has some resource codes in it like ERR_CODE_SYS_RESOURCE_FAILURE:1000,
                ERR_CODE_FILE_READ_ERROR:1001

Comment: So it's simple header, it won't be compiled, it's (or should be) included in some sources. Make sure that compiler can find a path to these files, they not need to be added into project (however, it would be recommended for clarity). Show us compiler error if it doesn't help.

Comment: Path is clearly specified in include directories, i've tried adding those files to source directory as well but nothing works.

Comment: Paste the whole error here.